# Find an ID through having a username?

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

SOLVED

THANKS TO HAR07 FOR HELPING ME OUT AND ANYONE THAT ELSE HAS COMMENTED!

```
public partial class xamlAuditorDashboard : Window
{
    cEvolve_SP sp = new cEvolve_SP(Properties.Settings.Default.AppConnectionString);
    List<cAuditTasksEntity> _tasks;
    cAuditUserEntity _loggedInUser;
    public xamlAuditorDashboard(cAuditUserEntity loggedInUser)
    {
        _loggedInUser = loggedInUser;
        InitializeComponent();
        _tasks = new List<cAuditTasksEntity>();
        Refresh();
    }

    private void Refresh()
    {

        var _AuditUserId = _loggedInUser;
        cAuditUserEntity user = _AuditUserId as cAuditUserEntity;

        int userid = user.AuditUserId;

        _tasks = sp.GetTasksByUser(userid).ToList();

        var result = (from cAuditTasksEntity tasks in _tasks
                      select tasks.TaskId).ToList();
        cmbToDoList.ItemsSource = result;

    }

    private void btnAudit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var Audit = cmbToDoList.SelectedItem;

        var _TransactionId = Audit;

        cAuditTransactionsEntity transaction = _TransactionId as cAuditTransactionsEntity;

        string transactionid = transaction.TransactionId;

        sp.GetTransactionInfo(transactionid);


    }
```

What I am trying to do is, from having a `TaskId` I want to find out the `TransactionId`.

From my code in my Refresh method I getting the `LoggedOnUser` and searching the `TaskTable` for it then to bring out any tasks that there ID is next to, then to display the `TaskIds' in a combobox on there page.

What i am looking to do is when they click on the `TaskId` in the combobox and click New Audit, another page will load up and display all different information.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgek2.png

This is the TaskTable, the TaskID is what shows up in there combobox.

When they select a new ID from there combobox and click next, I need it to find the transactionId next to the TaskId they clicked, then bring back:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/APp6E.png

all the information in the circle?

EDIT:

The cAuditTasksEntity:

```
namespace DAL
{
[Table(Name = "Audit_Tasks")]
public class cAuditTasksEntity
{

    private int _TaskId;
    private int _AuditUserId;
    private string _TransactionId;
    private string _TaskTypeId;
    private DateTime _Date;
    private string _AuditStatus;


    [Column(DbType = "INT", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int TaskId
    {
        get { return _TaskId; }
        set { _TaskId = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "INT")]
    public int AuditUserId
    {
        get { return _AuditUserId; }
        set { _AuditUserId = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "CHAR(32)")]
    public string TransactionId
    {
        get { return _TransactionId; }
        set { _TransactionId = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "CHAR(32)")]
    public string TaskTypeId
    {
        get { return _TaskTypeId; }
        set { _TaskTypeId = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "DATETIME")]
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _Date; }
        set { _Date = value; }
    }

    [Column(DbType = "VARCHAR(255)")]
    public string AuditStatus
    {
        get { return _AuditStatus; }
        set { _AuditStatus = value; }
    }



}
}
```

Also the properties i see are these 4 :

```
ToString();
GetHashCode();
GetType();
Equals();
```

EDIT2:

This is what `Audit.GetType();` is showing but I don't understand?

I added this code:

`var result = Audit.GetType();`

and then this set result to be equal to:

`{Name = "Int32" FullName = "System.Int32"`

Comment: You stated what you are going to do, and if your code and stored procs work properly that means you managed to get what you want. So what is the question actually?

Comment: @har07 The bit I'm stuck on is that I can find the transaction ID from the TaskId.

Comment: In btnAudit_Click method, isnt Audit.TransactionId what you are looking for? Assuming Audit is object that represent single row data in TaskTable, Audit.TaskId is the TaskId you are talking about and Audit.TransactionId is the TransactionID corresponding to that TaskID.. Am i missing sth about the situation?

Comment: @har07 All audit it doing it representing the TaskId they click on in the Combobox. When i debug i thought that on the line `cAuditTransactionsEntity transaction = _TransactionId as cAuditTransactionsEntity;` it would get the transactionid but transaction returns null.

Comment: @har07 When i try and do `Audit.` the only things that show is the `ToString` and the other 3 properties.

Comment: Audit is of type cAuditTasksEntity, can you post cAuditTasksEntity class definition with those 3 properties you mentioned?

Comment: @har07 I have added the  `cAuditTasksEntity` class and also i have added the 4 properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for, getting transactionId given TaskId:

```
var _TransactionId = (from task transactionid in _tasks 
                       where task.TaskId == (int)cmbToDoList.SelectedItem
                       select task.TransactionId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Nevermind _TransactionId brings me back the transactionid with just your code. Thanks for your help and support!